# SSRS : Fiscal Grouping

Tags: reporting-services

I need to group within my SSRS report by Fiscal Week, Month and Year. I'm having the user select a date then referencing a created table that houses the fiscal week, month year etc. for that calendar date. How do I group on this within SSRS?

Fiscal Table Sample Data

```
Calendar_Date: 04/28/2013
Fiscal_Week: 13
Fiscal_Month: 3
Fiscal_Year: 2013
```

I want the report to display like

> [image]

How do I do a grouping where I can group on the week and month of the selected date?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a group to be grouped on multiple fields, though it's not exactly intuitive.

When you add a group you can only choose one grouping expression:

[image]

However, when you've created the group you can add more grouping criteria:

[image]

Add in all your required fields here and it should group correctly by the various required fields.